# I need to find the projection of a vector onto the plane perpendicular to some other vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, projection-matrices

Specifically,

"Calculate the projection of the vector (1,2,3) onto the plane perpendicular to the vector (1,1,1)."

I am familiar with the projection formula, the projection vector $\mathbf v$ of $\mathbf w$, 
$\mathbf v = P_u \,\mathbf w = A^T(AA^T)^{-1}A \,\mathbf w$, where the rows of matrix A form a basis for the subspace U.   In this case, **w** = (1,2,3).
I cannot get my head around defining a subspace. From my understanding, the basis of a plane should need only two vectors. Please tell me if I'm wrong about this and why.

My question is:

- How do I define the matrix A based on the plane in the above question?

*Thanks.*

Comment: Hi, nice question! However, it would be *much* nicer if you were to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to edit your equations, which would probably attract more answerers. Cheers.

Comment: You can save yourself a lot of work by taking advantage of the fact that the projection onto the plane is the rejection from the plane’s normal vector—what’s left over after you subtract the projection onto the normal.

Answer (score 1):

Caution: in the definition of $A$, it must the **columns (and not the rows)** of matrix $A$ ...

i.e., matrix $A$ has a rectangular shape  ("portrait format" $3 \times 2$ and not "landscape format" $2 \times 3$) with its 2 columns equal to the basis on the space on which you project, here a plane.

You can take for example:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}\ \ 1 & \ \ 0\\
                   -1 & \ \ 1\\
                   \ \ 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$

(check that the columns of $A$ are orthogonal to $\begin{pmatrix}1\\
                   1\\
                  1
\end{pmatrix}$)

Comment: Thanks. But how do I form such a matrix?

Comment: I have added a possible $A$ in my answer. There are an infinity of such $A$, but at the end of the calculation (with the general formula), whatever $A$ you have chosen, the result (the projection matrix) is the same.

Comment: Thank you, this has helped my understanding a great deal.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the matrix A as the null-space of $
\left( {\matrix{
   1 & 1 & 1  \cr 
   0 & 0 & 0  \cr 
   0 & 0 & 0  \cr 
 } } \right)
$ ,
i.e. $
\left( {\matrix{
   1 & 1  \cr 
   { - 1} & 0  \cr 
   0 & { - 1}  \cr 
 } } \right)
$, apart for appropriately adjusting for "by-rows" or "by-columns" definition as advised in *JeanMarie*'s answer.

Note that, if you take any invertible matrix that contains the $(1,1,1)$ as first column (or row), then the 2nd and 3rd rows (columns) of its inverse will provide, by definition, such a null-space.
For example:
$$
S = \left( {\matrix{
   1 & 0 & 0  \cr 
   1 & 1 & 0  \cr 
   1 & 1 & 1  \cr 
 } } \right)\quad S^{\, - 1}  = \left( {\matrix{
   1 & 0 & 0  \cr 
   { - 1} & 1 & 0  \cr 
   0 & { - 1} & 1  \cr 
 } } \right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn’t say *which* plane perpendicular to $\mathbf n=(1,1,1)^T$ is meant, but since this doesn’t really affect the projection, let’s assume that the one through the origin was meant—the orthogonal complement of $\mathbf n$. You can use any basis of this space as the columns of the matrix $A$ in your formula.

The plane define by $\mathbf n$ consists of all solutions to the equation $(1,1,1)^T\cdot(x,y,z)^T=x+y+z=0$.  More generally, to find the orthogonal complement of a set of vectors $\mathbf v_1,\dots,\mathbf v_m$, you would solve the homogeneous system of linear equations $\mathbf v_1\cdot\mathbf x=0,\dots,\mathbf v_m\cdot\mathbf x=0$. The solution to this system consists of all elements of the null space of the matrix that has these vectors as rows, as you probably already know. One can find a basis for this space by row-reducing and reading one from the resulting matrix. We can do the same with one vector: the coefficient matrix is simply the vector itself: $\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$. This is already in row-reduced echelon form, so we immediately read from it that $(1,-1,0)^T$ and $(1,0,-1)^T$ are a basis for its null space, so one matrix that will work for the projection formula is $$A=\left[\begin{array}{rr}1&1\\-1&0\\0&-1\end{array}\right].$$ More generally, a basis for the orthogonal complement of a vector $(v_1,v_2,v_3,\dots,v_n)^T$ with $v_1\ne0$ is $$\begin{bmatrix}v_2\\-v_1\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}v_3\\0\\-v_1\\\vdots\\0\end{bmatrix},\cdots,\begin{bmatrix}v_n\\0\\0\\\vdots\\-v_1\end{bmatrix}.$$ (If $v_1=0$, there’s a similar-looking simple pattern that uses the first non-zero slot of the vector instead of the first.)

You can, however, save yourself some tedious matrix multiplications and inversions by approaching this problem from a different direction. A vector $\mathbf v$ can be decomposed into a component that lies in a subspspace $W$—its projection $P_W\mathbf v$ onto $W$—and a component that’s orthogonal to the space. In our case, this orthogonal component is simply the projection $P_{\mathbf n}\mathbf v$ of $\mathbf v$ onto the plane’s normal vector $\mathbf n$. Therefore, we have $P_W\mathbf v=\mathbf v-P_{\mathbf n}\mathbf v$ (which you might recognize as one of the steps in an iteration of the Gram-Schmidt process). This is known as the orthogonal *rejection* of $\mathbf v$ from $\mathbf n$. Using the well-known formula for the orthogonal projection of one vector onto another, this can be written as $$P_W\mathbf v=\mathbf v-{\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf n\over\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf n}\mathbf n.$$ If you need the actual projection matrix $P_W$, that can also be computed from the orthogonal projection onto $\mathbf n$. In matrix form, the above equation becomes $$P_W\mathbf v=\mathbf v-{\mathbf n\mathbf n^T\over\mathbf n^T\mathbf n}\mathbf v=\left(I-{\mathbf n\mathbf n^T\over\mathbf n^T\mathbf n}\right)\mathbf v.$$ The parenthesized expression is the matrix for projection onto $W$ and is a lot less work to compute than $A(A^TA)^{-1}A$. To illustrate, for this problem we have $$I-\frac13\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}-\frac13\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}=\left[\begin{array}{rrr}\frac23&-\frac13&-\frac13\\-\frac13&\frac23&-\frac13\\-\frac13&-\frac13&\frac23\end{array}\right]$$ which should be the same as the matrix that you got using the other method.